# Selection Changed Event is Rising when I clicked on Click Event handler

Tags: windows-phone-8

Sorry for the silly question.I even did not understand what should be given as title to this question.

I have 3 buttons and when I click them listboxes should be displayed.
And if I select an item in listbox it should be navigated and start playing.

When I click a button listbox is displaying and when an item is selected it is navigating to to other page and playing.After performing selection changed if I click any button I was getting error like

A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in tori.dll

An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in tori.dll

**Archieves .xaml:**

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,-951,0">
        <Button Name="btn1" Click="btn1_Click" Content="Daily" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,88,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="127" Height="72"/>
       <Button Name="btn2" Click="btn2_Click" Content="Weekly" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="132,88,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="72" Width="140"/>
      <Button Name="btn3" Click="btn3_Click" Content="CurrentMonth" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="277,88,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="72" Width="169"/>
                    <ListBox x:Name="itemsList" Margin="0,225,945,0"  
                SelectionChanged="itemsList_SelectionChanged">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Height="130">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image delay:LowProfileImageLoader.UriSource="{Binding ThumbnailUrl}" 
                               Grid.Column="0" 
                               Width="500" 
                               Height="125" 
                               VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                               Margin="6"/>
                        <StackPanel Margin="10,20,0,0"
                                    Grid.Column="1"
                                    Height="60"
                                    Orientation="Horizontal" 
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding title}" 
                                       FontSize="40" />

                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
       </Grid>
```

**Archieves.xaml.cs:**

```
namespace tori
{
    public partial class Archieves : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public Archieves()
       {
            InitializeComponent();
       }

    private void btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient downloader = new WebClient();
        Uri uri = new Uri(" http://www.toucheradio.com/RSSFeed/rssDaily.php ", UriKind.Absolute);
        downloader.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(ChannelDownloaded);
        downloader.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
    }

    void ChannelDownloaded(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Result == null || e.Error != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There was an error downloading the XML-file!");
        }


        else
        {
            // Deserialize if download succeeds

            XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);

            var queue = from item in document.Descendants("item")
                        select new Item
                        {
                            title = item.Element("title").Value
                            ,
                            link = item.Element("link").Value
                            ,
                            pubDate = item.Element("pubDate").Value
                            ,
                            ThumbnailUrl = item.Element(item.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("media") + "thumbnail").Attribute("url").Value
                            ,

                        };

            itemsList.ItemsSource = queue;
        }
    }

private void btn2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient downloader = new WebClient();
        Uri uri = new Uri(" http://www.toucheradio.com/RSSFeed/rssWeekly.php ", UriKind.Absolute);
        downloader.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(Channel1Downloaded);
        downloader.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
    }

       void Channel1Downloaded(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
       {
           if (e.Result == null || e.Error != null)
           {
               MessageBox.Show("There was an error downloading the XML-file!");
           }
        else
        {
            // Deserialize if download succeeds

            XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);

            var queue = from item in document.Descendants("item")
                        select new Item
                        {
                            title = item.Element("title").Value
                            ,
                            link = item.Element("link").Value
                            ,
                            pubDate = item.Element("pubDate").Value
                            ,
                            ThumbnailUrl = item.Element(item.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("media") + "thumbnail").Attribute("url").Value
                            ,

                        };

            itemsList.ItemsSource = queue;
        }
    }

private void btn3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        WebClient downloader = new WebClient();
        Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.toucheradio.com/RSSFeed/rssMonthly.php ", UriKind.Absolute);
        downloader.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(Channel2Downloaded);
        downloader.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
    }

    void Channel2Downloaded(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Result == null || e.Error != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There was an error downloading the XML-file!");
        }
        else
        {
            // Deserialize if download succeeds

            XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);

            var queue = from item in document.Descendants("item")
                        select new Item
                        {
                            title = item.Element("title").Value
                            ,
                            link = item.Element("link").Value
                            ,
                            pubDate = item.Element("pubDate").Value
                            ,

                            ThumbnailUrl = item.Element(item.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("media") + "thumbnail").Attribute("url").Value
                            ,

                        };

            itemsList.ItemsSource = queue;
        }
    }
    private void itemsList_SelectionChanged(Object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var app = App.Current as App;
        app.selectedItem = (Item)itemsList.SelectedItem;
        this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Details.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

**Item.cs:**

```
namespace tori
{
         public class Item
    {
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string ThumbnailUrl { get; set; }
        public string link { get; set; }
        public string pubDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Details.xaml:**

```
 <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Grid Height="617" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="-27,96,0,0">

            <Image x:Name="ThumbnailUrl" 

                               Width="279" 
                               Height="421" 
                               VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                               Margin="0,-29,204,225" />
            <Image x:Name="Image1" Tap="Image1_Tap"  Margin="46,430,354,92" Source="/Images/pausebutton.png"/>
         <TextBlock x:Name="title" FontSize="30" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="284,57,-50,436"  />
                <TextBlock x:Name="pubDate" FontSize="25" Margin="284,186,10,363"  />
            <MediaElement x:Name="MediaElement1" AutoPlay="True"  Margin="0,397,20,0" Height="94" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

**Details.xaml.cs:**

```
namespace tori
{
    public partial class Details : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        Item item;

    public Details()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


         var app = App.Current as App;
       item = app.selectedItem;
       title.Text = item.title;
       pubDate.Text = item.pubDate;
        ThumbnailUrl.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(item.ThumbnailUrl, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        string s = item.link;
        string url = s.Replace("archivesplayer", "hostArchivesURLForMobile");
        WebClient downloader = new WebClient();
        Uri uri = new Uri(url,UriKind.Absolute);
        downloader.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(Channel3Downloaded);
        downloader.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
    }

    void Channel3Downloaded(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textData = (string)e.Result;
        Regex urlRegex = new Regex("<td height=\"25\" align=\"center\">(?<url>.*)</td>");
        MatchCollection mc = urlRegex.Matches(textData);
        string url = "";
        if (mc.Count > 0)
        {
            url = mc[0].Groups["url"].Value;
             MediaElement1.Source = new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute);
             MediaElement1.Play();
        }
}
}
}
```

After performing selecting item if I click a button I was getting error in this line

title.Text = item.title;

Can anybody please tell me how can I overcome this  null exception.When I click on a button selection changed event is raising instead of click event. I am unable to know the reason for this.

Please anybody help me with this.

many Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When you change the `ItemsSource`, the `SelectionChanged` event is raised. I think whenever you change the `ItemsSource`, the selection is reset (that is - set to null (none selected)). And that's how it should be, otherwise an item that's not in the `ItemsSource` could be the `SelectedItem` which is just wrong.

Now, to fix your issue, just check if `SelectedItem != null` in `itemsList_SelectionChanged` method.

Something else about your code: the methods `btn1_Click`, `btn2_Click` and `btn3_Click` seem to only have minor differences, so you could put most of the code in one method and just pass it the url. That's even more important for the `ChannelDownloaded` methods (as they are much longer). Basically you want to reuse code as much as possible. That makes the code easier to read (as it's not 10 pages, but one, so to speak), and easier to maintain (if there's an error - you only need to fix it in one place).

Comment: I have changed the selection changed event to tap event and that solved my problem.I too have tried to write the code in a method and reuse.But I was little bit confused of passing the url.Can you please tell me of passing that url when clicked on a button.Thanking you.